# Given a triangle's circumcenter, incenter, and midpoint of one side, construct its vertices

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

> **Wernick's list problem number 69:** We want to find, with straightedge and compass, the vertices of triangle $\triangle ABC$ but we're only given:
>
> - its incenter, $I$
> - its circumcenter, $O$
> - the midpoint of side $a$, $M_a$

What I've done:

- draw half line $OM_a$, $r$
- draw $s$ perpendicular to $r$ passing through $M_a$ (this line contains side $BC$)
- draw $t$:a parallel to $r$ passing through $I$
- $Z = t \cap s$
- draw circle $c$ centered at $I$ passing thorugh $Z$ (this is the incircle of $\triangle ABC$)
- $Q = c \cap t \neq Z $
- reflect $Z$ at the point $M_a$ to find $T$.
- draw line $QT$ ($A$ is on this line).

I don't know how to finish. I suspect we can draw the radius of the circumcircle with Steiner porisms and that would end the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed find the circumcircle:

draw $IP \perp IO$ such that $P$ is in the incircle already drawn (there are two possible points for $P$ but it doesn't matter which one you pick).

let line $OP$ meet the circle centered at $P$ passing through $I$ at point $X$ ($X$ the point most distant to $O$).

The circle centered at $O$ with radius $OX$ is the circumcircle of $\triangle ABC$.

This is a result that is based on the distance $OI^2 = R^2 -2rR$.

From this, we easily get $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: I haven’t checked your construction, but if it is valid you have solved something an automated effort did not. http://poincare.matf.bg.ac.rs/%7Evesnap/animations/construction_0285.html

Comment: I can't access your link. But my construction works and you can check it on geogebra quickly. Thanks for pointing it to me. I hope I'm not the first to draw it because it is not any profound new discovery

Comment: Yes, apparently Problem 69 was solved when Wernick's list first came out.  I guess the automated solver couldn't figure it out.  So you can breathe a sigh of relief.   Maybe you need to take the answer I gave you for Problem 82 with a grain of salt.  But many people had probably tried to solve 82 before that article came out.

Comment: I thought so. I hesitated for a while before accepting your answer but the thruth is that problem seems a lot harder and after a little research and a couple tries I don't think anyone has an easy answer for that one in particular. I will keep your answer unless somebody magically come up with the correct answer